# Extract values from list and apply calculation on each

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe in the format below. I want to add a column `'Avg_cost_related'` which shows the average cost of all items related to an item:

```
Item Cost Related_items 

A    2$     ['E','D']
B    10$    ['A','F','C','E']
C    3$     ['E','D']
D    90$    ['B','D','F']
E    10$    ['A','C','F']
F    45$    ['E','D']
```

Result Required

```
Item Cost Related_items       Avg_cost_related

A    2     ['E','D']          50
B    10    ['A','F','C','E']  15
C    3     ['E','D']          50
D    90    ['B','D','F']      48.3
E    10    ['A','C','F']      16.6
F    45    ['E','D']          50
```

Comment: What have you tried yet?

Comment: @martineau Why would you remove the expected output?

Comment: Didn't realize that had been done (I was editing someone else's proposed edit). Sorry.

Comment: @celius-stingher if it was one of my attempted edits, sorry for the confusion.  I was trying this approach, and, well, it didn't go well: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/340493/471272

Comment: @martineau could you please add back the code you suggested?

Comment: What have you tried, and what research have you done? Can you share some more context for this? Using a DataFrame like this seems a bit awkward, no?

Comment: jsta0110: I didn't suggest any code. User @Grzegorz Skibinski posted an answer, but has since deleted it.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
df['Avg_cost_rel'] = df['Rel'].apply(lambda x: df[df['Item'].isin(x)]['Cost'].mean())
```

Output:

```
  Item  Cost           Rel  Avg_cost_rel
0    A     2        [E, D]     50.000000
1    B    10  [A, F, C, E]     15.000000
2    C     3        [E, D]     50.000000
3    D    90     [B, D, F]     48.333333
4    E    10     [A, C, F]     16.666667
5    F    45        [E, D]     50.000000
```